# How can I upload a sketch remotely from a distant location onto an arduino that is power by a battery

Tags: arduino-mega, sketch, hardware, prototype

Of course after developing a success full embedded product the next step would be making upgrades to compete favorably with new products in the market. Well making upgrades would require making adjustments in the sketch and Uploading it onto already made prototypes to cub the costs involved in by the hardware of a remotely located prototype. How can one upload a sketch from his location on to the prototype without going there psychically to upload through the port?

Answer (score 1):

Battery powered devices need a system where the device checks over Internet connection (WiFi, mobile) if a new firmware bin file is available on a specific location on a server. If the bin file is available the device can download it and apply.

One option how to apply the new bin is to use SD card and SD bootloader ([Zevero avr_boot](https://github.com/zevero/avr_boot)) The sketch saves the downloaded file on SD card and resets the MCU. The SD bootloader then loads the binary from the SD card to flash.

Other option if enough free flash memory is available is to use the InternalStorage object from [ArduinoOTA](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA) library. It uses the upper half of the flash memory to store the uploaded bin and then activates a modified Optiboot to copy the bin to run location and reset the MCU.

Comment: I  have options i think all i have to do is do some reading and seek out examples then i could do what ever i want to do. Thanks once again Im grateful for the information let me look out for the examples then I am sure I will be good to go then

Answer (score 0):

First you have to establish communication between Arduino and your computer. This communication could be wire (ex. LAN) or wireless.

Like Juraj said, you could use [ArduinoOTA](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA) with an additional WiFi or Ethernet module on your Arduino, as long as arduino is connected to the network and you know its address. I haven't tried it yet, so I don't know its reliability. Even so, it helps your problem

Comment: so why do you write an answer if you didn't test it?

Comment: I do not really know but its as if a few people or none have tried it. I really cannot afford wasting my money on unneccessary hardware if its not really worth a try. I wish i could get a clear highlight or possibility on how it would be done

Comment: @Sigma, the library has 38 stars  on GitHub in 1 year of existence even it is downloadable from Library Manager so most users don't have to go to GitHub. there are a few arduino forum threads where people ask for assistance to make it work and all were successful. right now here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=629780.msg4421977#msg4421977

Comment: @Juraj This is helpful I am going to give it a shot